# Mysterious Extra letter space showing up in words

Tags: css

I have an environment-specific CSS issue that I am trying to correct. When I test in Chrome, everything works fine. However, in the environment our application uses (based on Chromium), the word "Comedy" shows up as "Com edy" when the element gains focus. You can envision this element as similar to a poster you might see on a Netflix app. The text within is middle-center aligned to a rectangle box that once selected is enlarged and outlined. The issue with the extra letter space showing up appears only when the element has focus.

```
.poster {
    height: 117px;
    width: 208px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left 3px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    white-space: normal;
}

.poster:focus {
    z-index: 3;
}

.poster-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.poster:focus .poster-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1325);
    transform: scale(1.1325);
    border: 2px solid #0a141a;
    outline: 5px solid #00629b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<div class="poster">
    <div class="poster-content" style="background-image: none;">
        <div class="poster-title">Comedy</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS. This is not the full amount of CSS, but only what is active when the button is focused.

Comment: Can you supply a plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: I could, but that probably will not reproduce the issue. It seems to only happen in a custom browser we use for the app. I was hoping somebody else might have encountered a similar issue before and knows how to fix it.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann wouldn't this be an issue with the custom browser and not your code? I did however experience something kind of similiar and it turned out to be an issue with how the browser was rendering a custom font. Do you use any special fonts?

Comment: That might be it. We are using a custom font in the app.

Comment: Let me test. I can change it out to a standard font.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann run a test by replacing the font with like Arial or Times and see if it still exists

Comment: @zgood Yep, that was the problem. It was the custom font!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks to zgood for suggesting that it could be a custom font causing the issue. After testing with a standard font, it was no longer an issue. However, the bug in the CSS came from the following:

transform: scale(1.1325);

Changing the above to this:

transform: scale(1.1);

properly scales the text within the image even when still using the custom font.